# Microsoft-hosted CI quota of 25 parallel jobs

Tags: azure-devops

I wish I can procure more than 25 Microsoft-hosted parallel jobs capacity, but ADO won't let me. Is it feasible to overcome this quota?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an [Azure support plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/) associated with your Azure subscription, you can sign into the [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview) to submit a support ticket. They can help to buy more than 25 parallel jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You could overcome the limit of the Microsoft hosted parallel jobs by using self hosted jobs.

Microsoft mentions that:

> Visual Studio Enterprise subscribers get one self-hosted parallel job
> as a subscriber benefit.

You can get additional parallel jobs capacity by adding more visual studio subscribers on your Azure DevOps organization.

[image]

A detailed pricing and limits documentation page exists and you can check the costs for the parallel jobs.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/